# C# regex.split from richtextbox to range excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have 52 items stored in a RichTextBox, with one item per line.  So I have 52 lines.

I need to write the value of each line in the RichTextBox to Excel range C17:C42 & H17:H42

I use kind a code for write array in exact cell:

```
//for the first 26 data
range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C42", Missing.Value);
object[,] numbers1 = new object[26, 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
{
   numbers1[i, 0] = //here i want a read each line in richtextbox; 
}
range.Value2 = numbers1;
```

And here is how I read each line of the RichTextBox:

```
    string s = richTextBoxReceive.Text;
    var k = Regex.Split(s, "\\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);

    foreach (string str in k)
    {
        //do what you want
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
```

How do I combine these?

Comment: your math is wrong,c17:c42 have 26 cells in total so with h17:h42 it give 52,the data are number of my reading voltage from microcontroller in serial port,and i tried to bypass it to excel trough GUI

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work......

```
void insert( List<string> value)
{
    //for the first 26 data
    range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C42", Missing.Value);
    object[,] numbers1 = new object[26, 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        //value contains the data
        numbers1[i, 0] = value[i];
    }
     range.Value2 = numbers1;
}


//Get value from richtextbox
string s = richTextBoxReceive.Text;
var k = Regex.Split(s, "\\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
List<string> allvalue=new List<string>();

foreach (string str in k)
{
    allvalue.Add(str);
}
//call insert method to insert data into excell
insert(allvalue);
```

Comment: the code succesfully compiled but there are no value at excel at all

Comment: I think problem is in your this line of code 
 range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C42", Missing.Value);
    object[,] numbers1 = new object[26, 1];

Comment: what do you seggest?i'd already try serving more array & cell and data wont out in excel;
range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C67", Missing.Value);
            object[,] numbers1 = new object[52, 1];
            for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)

Comment: Please know perfectly how to insert value in excell array.

Comment: thankyou mr.pallob id already solved it,eventually i use array to read lines in richtextbox,since im not familiar with regex method,

Answer (score 0):

ok, I already solved this on my own. I used an array and read the richtextbox per line.

```
range = objSheet.get_Range("C17:C42", Missing.Value);
object[,] numbers3 = new object[26,1];
for (int i = 0; i<= richTextBoxReceive.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 25; j++)
    {
        numbers3[j, 0] = richTextBoxReceive.Lines[j + 1];
    }
}
```